# $_POST[] data at the top of page

Tags: php

I'm having about 20 `$_POST[]` items at the top of my page. Is there a quicker way of writing all these POST data rather than having to retype `$_POST` over and over again? (e.g.: may be by using a foreach loop ?)

```
/*    
$fName = $_POST['fName'];
$lName = $_POST['lName'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
*/


$arr = array('fName', 'lName', 'phone', 'address');

foreach ( $_POST as $data => $val ) {

}
```

Comment: DOWN-VOTER: Please leave a comment as to why my question was down voted. That helps. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keys and the variable names are same. [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) will help -

```
extract($_POST);
```

Will extract all the data in it and assign to the `variable`s named as the `key`s.

> Checks each key to see whether it has a valid variable name. It also checks for collisions with existing variables in the symbol table.

OR if you want to use `foreach` then -

```
foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
    $$key = $val;
}
```

This will assign the `value` to the variable with the name as `key`.

[Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: use of extract() function should be handled with care

Comment: @CyberSk8ter can you say why should it be handled with care?

Comment: @b0s3 What does a proper variable names mean?

Comment: @Fergoso Check the links. There are some limitations and vulnerabilities.

Comment: @Fergoso There are some rules to define variable names which you must follow.

Comment: @Fergoso from the php documentation>> Do not use extract() on untrusted data, like user input (i.e. $_GET, $_FILES, etc.). If you do, for example if you want to run old code that relies on register_globals temporarily, make sure you use one of the non-overwriting flags values such as EXTR_SKIP and be aware that you should extract in the same order that's defined in variables_order within the php.ini.